# Using Custom Libraries

Tags: android, debugging, libraries, android-preferences

So I'm pretty new to Android Development and I'm curious if I'm missing anything when I'm importing libraries into my android project. I followed [this guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html) on android website and made a new project out of existing code then added it as a library into my own project. The problem is everything errors out, `R` cannot be resolved as a variable so I tried to clean my project and it does nothing. I import `R` then it can't find any of my activities. So there's my first problem.

The library I'm using is This [Color Picker](https://github.com/attenzione/android-ColorPickerPreference) and really on the homepage it just says to use the xml and add it to my preferences but my preferences doesn't seem to recognize it.

I'm obviously doing something wrong but can't seem to find a decent tutorial to walk me through adding custom libraries to my project. I was hoping someone with more experience could help me find the root of my errors or point me to a tutorial so I can start the import process from scratch.

Am [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VN8pK.jpg) of my settings file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The library I'm using is This Color Picker

Any library that doesn't publish a complete sample app that uses the library should be ignored, IMHO.

> I'm obviously doing something wrong

Presumably, there is no color resource named `pumpkin_orange` in your project. There definitely is no such resource in the library. Either define this color resource, or replace `@color/pumpkin_orange` with a literal color or some color resource that you define.

Your `R` class does not exist because you have bugs in your resources (like the `settings.xml` one) and/or your manifest. Once those bugs are cleared up, your `R` class should generate properly.

Comment: Ok, cool thanks for helping me. First where would I define @color? do I need a color.xml file similar to strings.xml? Second so you're saying to find a new library since this one is broken?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee: "First where would I define @color?" -- you would define color resources in `res/values/colors.xml`, typically: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color "Second so you're saying to find a new library since this one is broken?" -- not necessarily broken, but not friendly, either, particularly somebody "pretty new to Android Development".

Comment: Kk, I'll see if I can find a different library. Thanks!

Comment: @Howdy_McGee: Mine isn't nearly as pretty, but it at least has a demonstration app: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-colormixer

Comment: I tried to use yours but it kept telling me it wouldn't build and when I checked out the build path it was saying I was missing a few jar files that I guess didn't come with the linked package.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee: That is covered in the README in the Dependencies section.